# mod_rewrite not working as think it should

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to apply some rewrite rules for my website, and don't know what I'm doing wrong...
thats what I'm trying, example:

this URL: www.mysite.com/contact/
should open: www.mysite.com/dv/contact/

or

this URL: www.mysite.com/
Should open: www.mysite.com/dv/

Here what I wrote on htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://(www\.|.{0})mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .com/? .com/dv/
```

but looks like the rule is not matching or something...

I tested a more simple rule just to check if mod_rewrite is doing good, and it is.

I tested the regex through the tool on http://regexpal.com/, and it's maching ok

What could I been doing wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!dv/).*)$ /dv/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: there will be cases when it will be subdomains. I want the rule to match only when there is no subdomains, www.mysite.com in the example, in this case I need a rewriteCond, don't I?

Comment: Yes that's right. I added a `RewriteCond` for that requirement.